# I am trying to search a keyword on youtube using Selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new with selenium and I am just exploring. I was trying to search a keyword on youtube using Selenium in python. And I ran into some errors.

This is the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/aksch/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://youtube.com")
searchBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"search\"]")
searchButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"search-icon-legacy\"]")

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(searchBox))
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for page to load")

searchBox.send_keys("Something")
searchButton.click()
```

And this is the error

```
C:\Users\aksch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe C:/Users/aksch/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/aksch/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(searchBox))
  File "C:\Users\aksch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 71, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
  File "C:\Users\aksch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 64, in __call__
    return _find_element(driver, self.locator)
  File "C:\Users\aksch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 411, in _find_element
    return driver.find_element(*by)
TypeError: find_element() argument after * must be an iterable, not WebElement

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your error is

Basically, some EC (Expected Conditions) methods use locators, while some use elements. The one you used only accepts a locator, but you provided an element instead.

> `element is a WebElement object. locator is a tuple of (by, path).

`

Reference:-  [How do I fix the TypeError raised when trying to find an element using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43801836/how-do-i-fix-the-typeerror-raised-when-trying-to-find-an-element-using-selenium)

Do it like this:-

```
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/.../Downloads/.../chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://youtube.com")
time.sleep(5)
driver.maximize_window()
searchBox = driver.find_element_by_class_name("style-scope ytd-searchbox")
searchButton = driver.find_element_by_id("search-icon-legacy")
searchBox.send_keys("Something")
searchButton.click()
```

Comment: I have one more doubt, Why does "driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]')" this not work?

Comment: That was not the problem part. The problem part is `.until(EC.presence_of_element_located` Like I said. Expected Conditions might use `locator` or `element` . You were giving an `element` found by `xpath` . `EC` expected a `tuple`

Comment: When I used your code and used "driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]')" instead of "driver.find_element_by_class_name("style-scope ytd-searchbox")" I get an "element not interactable" error.

Comment: The error " Message: element not interactable " mostly occurs when your element is not clickable or it is not visible yet, and you should click or choose one other element before it. Then your element will get displayed and you can modify it.

Comment: I found the problem, I had to use the full xpath.

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work for you.. there is a change in syntax for Expected Condition So it will take input as locator type and locator

check your locator for input box it's not locating that I have corrected that as well

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users///chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://youtube.com")
driver.maximize_window()
searchBox = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#search-form #container input")
searchButton = driver.find_element_by_id("search-icon-legacy")

try:
     WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#search-form #container input")))
except TimeoutException:
     print("Timed out waiting for page to load")


searchBox.send_keys("Something")
searchButton.click()
```

Answer (score -1):

The point is that the code is faster than uploading the website. So, after opening the website, you should add sleep time to the program.

```
from time import sleep
sleep(10)
```

Here I add 10 sec sleep time. So, after each line, just add this sleep.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/aksch/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
sleep(3)
```

Also, use a print to check in which line you are stuck.